# why am i getting this error while mounting internal ssd partition?

Tags: windows-7, centos-7

[image]

i have dual boot windows and cent os 7.Last time i used windows go to to install windows 10 on my usb drive **E:**.
Also i made the parton E as active partition to boot windows 10 from the USB.

Now i linux i can't mount the two partitions labeled "Local disk ssd"

Also i have problem booting into windows.

Marked in red below are windows partition
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might need to disable "Fast Startup" in Windows 10.

That feature leaves the NFTS filesystem in an inconsistent state for the sake of faster shutdown and boot times.

http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37059/~/windows-10%3A-enable-or-disable-fast-startup

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY

where XY is the partition

e.g sda2 or sdb1

then mount

sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdXY
```

Mounting drive as read only:

```
$ sudo mount -o ro /dev/[partition /media/[mounting point]
```

Another option is to repair the disk under Ubuntu with ntfsfix:

```
$ ntfsfix /dev/[partition]
```

Since it says it is an unclean file system, you may have registries or drivers that are corrupt.

Please provide more information.  Did you partition these all on the same disk drive?  Since you specifically said the recovery partition is on the E: drive, I wonder.